# why can't remove the Image frequency using a band-pass filter?

Tags: telecommunication, communication, digital-communication

**why can't remove the Image frequency using a band-pass filter?**
I've been asked to search for the reason why we can't use BPF (band-pass filter) in order to remove the effects of the Image frequency?

I've searched but couldn't find anything useful about it.
I would be glad if you could help me.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  You certainly can remove an image with a bandpass filter placed before a mixer.  Please show a block diagram of your proposed system, indicating where the filters are.

Answer (score 2):

You only know something is an "image frequency" because you know what the signal was like *before* you sampled it and reduced its bandwidth.

Do an experiment, either with real hardware or a computer simulation. Use a sampling rate of say 1000/sec and sample analog sine wave signals at 200 Hz and 800 Hz. The sampled data will be *identical* even though you would describe the sampled 800 Hz as an "image frequency".